# Django UnicodeDecodeError during error reporting

Tags: python, django, error-reporting

Error reporting is constantly crashing. In the traceback, I first get the actual error, then many times the same

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/exc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/var/www/exc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/var/www/exc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/var/www/exc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/var/www/exc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/var/www/exc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "/var/www/exc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
  File "/var/www/exc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am using `Python3.6` and `Django==2.2`. I do not understand where the `UnicodeDecodeError` comes from.

Running on production server

```
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
import sys
from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter

request = RequestFactory().get('/dummy')
exc_info = sys.exc_info()
reporter = ExceptionReporter(request, is_email=True, *exc_info)
reporter.get_traceback_html()
```

works without crashing.

I am running my website with gunicorn, using the following command

`/var/www/exc2-backend/.venv/bin/gunicorn exc2_backend.wsgi --name "exc2_backend" --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --user="www-data" --group="www-data"`

I narrowed down the problem, which happens here

```
from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter, CURRENT_DIR, DEBUG_ENGINE
from pathlib import Path

with Path(CURRENT_DIR, 'templates', 'technical_500.html').open() as fh:
    data = fh.read()
```

if I change to `Path(...).open(encoding='utf8')`, there is no error.

The error does not happen with the shell, only when code is run with gunicorn.

On the server, even through gunicorn, `sys.getdefaultencoding()` return `utf-8`, but `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` returns `ANSI_X3.4-1968`!

Any ideas?

Comment: It happens whenever error reporting is being used. So that I do not get an email reporting the error. I can only see the error by looking at the logs on the server. The website still runs and I get still more or less see the errors, but I'd rather get them by email, as it's usually done.

Comment: yes, as `www-data`, but having the same locale

Comment: it's `en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

The locale I had set in Gunicorn (`fr_FR.UTF8`) was not installed on the system, so somehow Python was defaulting to the `ANSI_X3.4-1968` encoding.

The solution was to install the missing locale: `sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8`